# CSS triangle over a div using :before and :after - weird offset, how to fix?

Tags: html, css

I have created a right angled triangle over a div using css. The problem is that the right border of the triangle and the right border of the div do not align. The triangle is offset by a bit. I do not understand how I can solve this.

Here is the jsfiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/hgy1yqcj/

My html is as follows :

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="arrow_box">blah blah</div>
</div>
```

And my CSS is as follows:

```
.outer{
 padding:20px;
}

.arrow_box {
width: 116px;
z-index: 2;
position: relative;
background: #ffffff;
border: 2px solid #cdcdcd;
}

.arrow_box:after, .arrow_box:before {
z-index: 2;
bottom: 100%;
border: solid transparent;
content: " ";
height: 0;
width: 0;
position: absolute;
}

.arrow_box:after {
z-index: 2;
right: 2.5px;
border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
border-width: 0 0px 12px 12px;
}

.arrow_box:before {
z-index: 2;
right: 0px;
border-bottom-color: #cdcdcd;
border-width: 0 0px 15px 15px;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because of the 2px border. Can be solved by adding `margin-right:-2px;` to the triangle so as to move it right by 2px.

```css
.outer {
  padding: 20px;
}
.arrow_box {
  width: 116px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: 2px solid #cdcdcd;
}
.arrow_box:after,
.arrow_box:before {
  z-index: 2;
  bottom: 100%;
  border: solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -2px;
  //border-right: 0px solid #cdcdcd;

}
.arrow_box:after {
  z-index: 2;
  right: 2.5px;
  border-bottom-color: #ffffff;
  border-width: 0 0px 12px 12px;
}
.arrow_box:before {
  z-index: 2;
  right: 0px;
  border-bottom-color: #cdcdcd;
  border-width: 0 0px 15px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="arrow_box">blah blah</div>
</div>
```